# Convert string into JSON object property

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON a object named `Task` with a set of properties.
I also have a string: `var customId = Custom_x005f_f3e0e66125c74ee785e8ec6965446416"`.
I would like to get the value `Task.Custom_x005f_f3e0e66125c74ee785e8ec6965446416` using my string variable.

Would you know how to do that ?

Please let me know if I'm not clear enough. Thanks.

Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use this:

```
var string = "Custom_x005f_f3e0e66125c74ee785e8ec6965446416";
vr myVar = Task[string];// Task.Custom_x005f_f3e0e66125c74ee785e8ec6965446416
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the bracket notation:

```
var customId = "Custom_x005f_f3e0e66125c74ee785e8ec6965446416";
var value = Task[customId];
```